# Expand User.Identity properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have a site with `frontend` and `admin panel`. Both have login page and user should be able to login on both `frontent` and `admin panel` with different user. By default `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is used to check if user is currently logged in, I want something like `User.Identity.IsAdminPanelAuthenticated`. So if a user only logged in on `admin panel` but not on frontend then `IsAuthenticated` will return `false` but `IsAdminPanelAuthenticated` will return `true`.

Comment: How do you determine if they are an Admin?

Comment: I have claims and custom authorize attribute to do that

Comment: Same website/project or two different websites?

Comment: same project and same domain. I know I should've gone with different project because it causes me a lot of problem so far. I didn't know it's not possible to use more than 1 instances in ASP Identity like previous Membership framework when I started the project.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that.  I don't really understand your logic.  If a user is logged in to a website, then the user is logged in.  It doesn't matter how you've sectioned off your website.

Comment: no because I want to separate between frontend and admin panel because both is using different database. Admin panel is for employee to configure content on frontend, while frontend is for enduser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81827/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-warheat1990).